# What does "B(int b=0):b(b){}" mean?

Tags: c++, class

What does `B(int b=0):b(b){}` mean in the following portion of code?

```
class B
{
    int b;
public:
    B(int b=0):b(b){}
 };
```

Comment: It defines a constructor for class `B`, taking one optional `int` parameter (if omitted, the default value of `0` is used). This constructor initializes the member variable of the class, named `b`, with the value of said parameter.

Comment: Just google these terms together with C++: Constructors, default arguments, and initializer lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an empty constructor definition.

```
class B
{
    int b;
public:
    B (int b = 0) //Default initialize b to 0
        : b(b) //Initialize member b to parameter b
    { } //Empty constructor definition
};
```

---

You could write instead of the constructor

```
B (int b = 0)
    : b(b)
{ }
```

also this:

```
B (int b = 0)
{
    this->b = b;
}
```

Comment: But those two ways aren't the same (for `const` and class type objects).

Comment: Of course not, but this right here is an `int b;`